# Difference between left touch down and right touch down

Tags: c#, wpf, touchscreen, mousedown

I have a problem with my touchscreen so I would like to know what is the difference between a left TouchDown and a right TouchDown. I need to understand if there is a pattern that can explain my problem. The only set that is not working is the one I want.

Trying to click on a MainWindow button after a pop-up has been closed:

- Using Mouse + MouseDown event => Working
- Using left Touch screen + MouseDown event => Not working, I need to touch twice the button to have it work.
- Using right Touch screen (holding the touch) + MouseDown event => Working
- Using left Touch screen + TouchDown => Working (but the goal is to not use this method as I have a lot of buttons, implementing TouchDown and MouseDown is not a way to go)

Why does the right touch works with the MouseDown event and not the left touch ?
What is the difference between the two ?

Thank you

Comment: do you have the configuration for the mouse setup properly ..? this is the only thing that I can think of..

Comment: I don't have a touch screen but mouse pad for laptops for example should all use the same `Touch property` in a similar way..

Comment: Sorry it was the "pen" property. The Touch tab of the Pen and Touch windows option are the following: Double-tap: Double-click ; Press and hold: Right-click. But there is no single tap, is it normal ?